# flip set of pixels with respect to a given row coordinate

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm trying to write a program that flips a region(represented as a set of Segments) with respect to a given row coordinate.
I don't know c++ well, so I got some errors I don't know why they appeared and how to fixed them.
Here is what I got so far:

```
struct Segment
{
    int row;
    int colStart;
    int colStop;
};

std::vector<Segment> FlipVertically(const std::vector<Segment>& region, const int flipRow){
    std::vector<Segment> vec, more, less;
    for (std::vector<Segment>::reverse_iterator it = region.rbegin(); it != region.rend(); ++it){
        if ((*it).row > flipRow){
                more.insert(more.begin(), *it);
            }
        else{less.insert(less.begin(), *it);}
        };
    std::sort(more.begin(), more.end(), [](Segment const &a, Segment const &b){
        return a.row > b.row;
        });
    std::sort(less.begin(), less.end(), [](Segment const &a, Segment const &b){
        return a.row > b.row;
        });
    vec.insert(vec.end(), more.begin(), more.end());
    vec.insert(vec.end(), less.begin(), less.end());
    int counter = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while(i + 1 < vec.size()){
        if (vec[i].row == vec[i + 1].row){
            vec[i].row = counter;
            }
        else{
            vec[i].row = counter;
            counter++;}
        i++;
        }
    vec.back().row = counter;    
    return vec;
    }
```

The function should return Segments stored from top to bottom row, and in the same row from left to right column.
It says there is an error in while loop: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare].
Also, I'm looking for tips to improve my algorithm because I feel it is not good because of two sorts I do after dividing data. I was thinking if it is possible to iterate through region and place Segments in the order I want during first iteration but wasn't able to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```cpp
   for (std::vector<Segment>::reverse_iterator it = region.rbegin(); it != region.rend(); ++it){
```

needs to be changed to

```cpp
   for (std::vector<Segment>::const_reverse_iterator it = region.rbegin(); it != region.rend(); ++it){
```

since `region` is a *const* container. Thus calling `begin/rbegin/end/rend` on `const` containers will return `const_...iterator_type...` for these.

But, better yet, use `auto` to simplify.

```cpp
for(auto it = region.rbegin(); it != region.rend(); ++it)
```

But the whole first loop can be modified to go faster by looping forward

```cpp
   for(auto const& value : region)
   {
      if(value.row > flipRow)
      {
         more.push_back(value);
      }
      else
      {
         less.push_back(value);
      }
   }
```

On a final note. The first part of you algorithm

```cpp
    std::vector<Segment> vec, more, less;
    for (std::vector<Segment>::reverse_iterator it = region.rbegin(); it != region.rend(); ++it){
        if ((*it).row > flipRow){
                more.insert(more.begin(), *it);
            }
        else{less.insert(less.begin(), *it);}
        };
    std::sort(more.begin(), more.end(), [](Segment const &a, Segment const &b){
        return a.row > b.row;
        });
    std::sort(less.begin(), less.end(), [](Segment const &a, Segment const &b){
        return a.row > b.row;
        });
    vec.insert(vec.end(), more.begin(), more.end());
    vec.insert(vec.end(), less.begin(), less.end());
```

can be condensed down to

```cpp
   auto vec = region;
   std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](Segment const& a, Segment const& b) {
      return a.row > b.row;
   });
```

This rendering the use of `flipRow` obsolete. If you think it is needed
then there is likely another flaw in the implementation.

Comment: There's a standard library algorithm for the first loop called [`std::partition_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy)

Comment: I was thinking of proposing [std::partial_sort_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy) but code just looked messier.